# How can I update the property value in xml file which was serialized by custom object?

Tags: c#, xml

I have a serialized class which each property has the SerializableAttribute attribute applied.I can get the object deserilized from xml file and changing the content of properties in application.I want to save the content of changed object to orignal xml which deserilized from.Is there any simple way to update changing object content to xml file without resaving the whole file?

```
[Serializable]
public class Product
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public double Name {get; set;}

    [XmlAttribute]
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: is it a list of products or just one product per file

Comment: Hello K.B ,it is only one product and one xml file

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

1. Deserialize the object.
2. Modify the value.
3. Serialize it again.

Comment: dear nsgocev, I did step1 and step 2, but if i serialize it again it will be update the content of Name property.

Comment: @Whistler if you only changed the `Value`, then `Name` should be the same. Ultimately, you can't edit xml in-place - you need to rewrite the entire file, to account for changes in lengths etc. Files don't actually have an "insert" / "remove" concept - just append, overwrite and set-length.

Comment: Hi Marc, if i used serialized/deserialized will rewrite the entire file.Did i use linq to xml to update the xml file to update the xml file content?

Comment: LINQ-to-XML doesn't do in-place updates for exactly the same reasons. It allows you to **rewrite** a file, but not to alter it in-place

Comment: @Whistler as Marc said - there is no way to update the field in place without resaving the whole file. Even if you edit the xml in place (as a string) - you will need to resave the entire file again.